# Sending form data as an array

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have a form where I have five fields for one loop and I want to send it to an API in order to save it to a database.

This is the **product.page.html**

```
<details *ngFor="let product of products;">
    <summary>{{product.name}}</summary>
    <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="categoryId" value="{{product.categoryId}}"></ion-input>
    <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="productId" value="{{product.id}}"></ion-input>

    <ion-row>
        <ion-col>
            <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="minPrice" value="{{product.minPrice}}"></ion-input>
        </ion-col>

        <ion-col>
            <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="maxPrice" value="{{product.maxPrice}}"></ion-input>
        </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row>
        <ion-col>
            For Sale:
            <ion-select [(ngModel)]="forSale" interface="popover">
                <ion-select-option value="0">No</ion-select-option>
                <ion-select-option value="1">Yes</ion-select-option>
            </ion-select>
        </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
</details>
<ion-button type="button" (click)="saveDetails()">Save</ion-button>
```

This is the **product.page.ts**

```
...
categoryId: any;
productId: any;
minPrice: any;
maxPrice: any;
forSale: any;

saveDetails() {

    let data = {categoryId: this.categoryId, productId: this.productId, minPrice: this.minPrice, maxPrice: this.maxPrice, forSale: this.forSale};

    this.http.post('http://example.com/api/saveDetails', JSON.stringify(data))
    .subscribe((res: any) => {console.log("success");});
}
```

The problem is that I don't know how to send that data in the below format because the API only accepts this format to save it into the database.

```
"productList": [
    {
        //First
        'categoryId': 'value',
        'productId': 'value',
        'minPrice': 'value',
        'maxPrice': 'value',
        'forSale': 'value'
    },
    {
        //Second
        'categoryId': 'value',
        'productId': 'value',
        'minPrice': 'value',
        'maxPrice': 'value',
        'forSale': 'value'
    },
    ...
],
```

Any help to make it possible will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you please post your generated JSON here ?

Comment: @bZezzz When i hit the save button then I get undefined error in chrome console. So, no JSON is generated.

Comment: `console.log(JSON.stringify(data))` ?

Comment: the respond is {}

Comment: @bZezzz what do you think. What is the problem?

Comment: Where did you put `console.log(JSON.stringify(data))` ? Just after your `let data` ?

Comment: @bZezzz yes after the let data ={}

Comment: Hmm, seem to have no data passed to your function, all values are empty.. When you logForm() what you get ?  If you use ngModel within a Form tag, you have to provide a name property

Comment: @bZezzz in logForm() i also get nothing. My thinking is that the form is not correctly configured in order to show it as an array in the TS file. For now, let's ignore the sending to the server part and only focus on showing the form data in the console of chrome.

Answer (score -1):

For example you can use `ReplaySubject`. Do this in `product.page.ts`:

```
private readonly dataSend = new ReplaySubject();

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.dataSend.pipe(
    scan((acc, current) => {
      acc.push(current)
      return acc;
    }, []), 
    debounceTime(1),
    switchMap(data => this.http.post('http://example.com/api/saveDetails', data))
).subscribe(console.log);
}
```

...

```
saveDetails() {

    const data = {categoryId: this.categoryId, productId: this.productId, minPrice: this.minPrice, maxPrice: this.maxPrice, forSale: this.forSale};

    this.dataSend.next(data);
}
```

...

```
ngOnDestroy(): void {
  this.dataSend.complete();
}
```

Comment: if you need `productList` property in sent data: `this.http.post('http://example.com/api/saveDetails', {productList: data})`

Comment: Hi. It didn't work.